# How to detect if quick type option is on during typing

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, ios8

How it is possible to detect if person is using quick type option with keyboard, and programmatically calculate size of quick type option bar.

I do some investigations and it is possible to calculate size of the keyboard but not size of quick type bar.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time i notice `UIKeyboardNotification` have a notification that can handle this problem. This notifications is `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification`.

Small code example:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame:) name:UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

To receive notification :

```
- (void)keyboardWillChangeFrame:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{
                         [self.bottomConstrein setConstant:50];
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }];
}
```